# Is there a formalisation for REST principle over JSON-only messages?

Tags: json, http, specifications

I'm building a platform on [fluence](https://fluence.network) and can only send text and JSON over the network between the client and the backend. Yet, we already build an OpenAPI specifications. Is there a convention for transmitting REST-compliants messages over JSON?

Comment: REST is an architectural style that should be used if your services are consumed by clients not under your control or if your client should be able to interact with a plethora of other services. Messages exchanged in that architecture should follow common standards as defined by [media types standardized by IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) which should be negotiated about by both sender and receiver. There are a couple of JSON based media types such as hal+json, siren, collections+json, json-api, ... just to name a few

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure about what you mean by "REST compliant on JSON", but REST is more an architectural protocol that is not even restricted to HTTP, much less by a data representation format like JSON. REST is more about exposing application state, application actions/flow and application semantics, using the underlying characteristics of the application protocol. For example in the case of http, using status codes semantics for exposing app semantics, having single resource URIs, having actions based on corresponding http verbs GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc; following  precepts like verb idempotency or non idempotency for GET & POST respectively for example; guiding application flow via Hypermedia links etc

In short, if the question is if there is Restful standard for JSON, the short answer is no. Nevertheless, please read about Hypermedia-aware formats, and hypermedia aware JSON, because such standardization efforts have been tried and is a current research area.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that :)

Comment: You are welcomed, as Roman mentioned above, there are a couple of standardization attempts in what is known as hypermedia aware JSON, and there you'll find media types like collection+json, json-ld plus Hydra, siren; etc. In my personal experience, usage of these formats (although very promising) is not very widespread, and forcing content negotiation using those, could unnecessarily hinder your project. They are nevertheless very promising and I hope some of them become standards in the not too distant future.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with your negotiation objection. You might start with one or two types and add further ones later. The beauty of REST is that is explicitely enforces evolvability in future. If you limit yourself to only one or two media-types you either force the client to adapt or you restrict yourself (your server) from interacting with potential clients (customers) of your system. Think of EDI i.e. where you have lots of different systems that exchange more or less standardized messages. Only speaking EDIFACT might be sufficient but prevent half of the world from using your system

Comment: In an environment where you select your own development stack you have flexibility to do as you will. Some clients (most clients) force you into a direction where the usage of those types may be complicated. Either the framework http layer doesn't support the types; the system API clients won't support those types most of the times either. Documentation is in some cases precarious, etc. I personally wanted to add support to them, but at the end the people putting the money wouldn't comply with that desire as they wouldn't see a return of investment for adding that.

Comment: Or in a company where technology & standards lie at the forefront that may be feasible. But product oriented companies rushing to achieve time to market for particular functionality, seems like an uphill battle, but is encouraging to hear success stories regarding their adoption.

Comment: A service that follows the principles of a REST architecture does not need out-of-band documentation as the affordance of the exchanged representations is enough. REST works on a "server teaches clients what they need to know" premis, similar to HTML does with Forms. If you still need some documentation your API is probably still RPC based. I admit though that the ROI for pragmatic, RPC-esque APIs may be higher at start. Over time a true REST based solution may perform better in terms of scalability and extensibility though.

Comment: I wasn't refering to the documentation of the specific API though. I was refering to Hypermedia aware formats documentation on the web and its implementation so that that you can effectively use it; you are refering to the custom semantic metadata linking that some of those formats offer to make them self descriptive. Other problems include tool maturity (for example, your postman doesn't parse out the box those types, or your typical App controller layer in common frameworks won't either), RFCs for them are mostly not yet approved. Do we agree they aren't ready for mass adoption yet?

Comment: I basically agree with you in most points, except following: I believe tool maturity and support for these standards today, are in a point where the cost/benefit ratio doesn't play in favor of their adoption. Other than that, I believe that sooner than later their adoption is enevitable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a convention for transmitting REST-compliants messages over JSON?

The central piece of REST is the *resource*. And a resource can have multiple *representations*. The goal behind supporting multiple representations for the same resource is that the client would be able to choose the representation that best suit their needs. It's called *content negotiation*.

But it's important to stress that fact that there's no restrictions on the [media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) that REST applications can use to represent the resources. It's up to each implementation.

We *frequently* see REST APIs using JSON as a mean to represent resources because JSON is a pretty popular data format and can be easily parsed by a number of programming languages.

Comment: I know that, but my question was more about transmitting REST compliants message *without* any HTTP architecture involve, like on a socket or a FIFO.